# Как поменять TTL в Windows без перезагрузки?

Tags: windows, wifi, mobile

У меня на мобиле МТС и я раздаю Интернет на PC, раздача ведется с DefaultTTL 65, выставленной на компьютере, ipv6 отключен.

Довольно часто, оператор каким-то образом определяет, что я веду раздачу и наглухо банит раздачу(инет на мобиле есть, на PC нет). 
Далее я проделываю "магию":

1. меняю TTL на 64, перезагружаюсь, инет появляется, но с платной
   раздачей
2. меняю TTL на 65, перезагружаюсь, инет появляется, теперь
   с бесплатной раздачей
3. живу не тужу пару дней, далее сначала

Раздача, как всегда, обрывается в самый ответственный момент, и перезагрузка отнимает минут 10. 
На linux я бы проделал что-то вроде **/ect/init.d/networking restart**. Как менять TTL без перезагрузки на Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Без перезагрузки: `netsh int ipv4 set glob defaultcurhoplimit=65`

Answer (score 0):

Оставьте в покое 65 TTL, просто подключите к раздаваемому интернету еще одно любое устройство и интернет на компьютере появится, сам так делаю.